# Minimum cost for colouring the house?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I came across below problem

> There are N houses in a row. Each house can be painted in either Red,
>   Green or Blue color. The cost of colouring each house in each of the
>   colours is different. Find the colour of each house such that no two
>   adjacent houses have the same colour and the total cost of colouring
>   all the houses is minimum.

Here is the [complete question](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=9941005)

The problem to me looks bit confusing, as  objective is to minmize the cost and ensure that no adjacent house have same colour. In that case should not i select
 the just two colours out of three whose cost is minimum.

Say here is the cost of colours

1. Red   $100
2. Green $200
3. Blue  $300

I have 5 row houses to paint

**Here will be my Algo**

1. Select Red and Green colour as their cost is minimum
2. calculate 5%2.

   If 5%2 == 1 then start from last and  select the colour of last house as Red($100). Now choose the alternate colour

   If 5%2 == 0 then start from beginning and  choose the alternate colour

I see [Is "house coloring with three colors" NP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630743/is-house-coloring-with-three-colors-np)  suggested the dynamic programming But i am not sure what is wrong with my approach and why dynamic  programming is required here ?

Comment: Probably the author intended a cost for each house-color combination, so that you can't statically choose your colors. Otherwise, that's a reasonable idea.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat here main intention is  `no two adjacent houses have the same colour and the total cost of colouring all the houses is minimum.` so  even if author intended a cost for each house-color combination, minimum cost will be what i explained in my algo. Here is the full question https://www.careercup.com/question?id=9941005

Comment: There's a clarification there that painting house 1 red does not always cost the same as painting house 2 red.

Comment: And in general, you need all of the colors, e.g., if there are three houses, and #1's cheapest is red, #2's cheapest is green, and #3's cheapest is blue.

Answer (score 0):

This is (presumably) a homework problem.  I think the intention is to teach you to implement a greedy algorithm:

1. Paint the first house using the cheapest color ("red").
2. Paint the next house using the cheapest color available.

The second will alternate between "red" and "green", but you don't have to choose the colors in advance.

If I were assigning this problem, the next problem would be "And solve this assuming you have only enough paint for one red house".

Comment: I believe your answer agrees the algo I suggested. In your Algo also you are not going to use blue color ever. Right ? I did not get how DP is going to help here as suggested in answers at https://www.careercup.com/question?id=9941005 ?